# VB.net TreeView with checkboxes only on certain layers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, treeview

Does anyone know of a way to set a TreeView control to only show checkboxes on particular nodes or layers?

I have a TreeView but I only want the checkbox's to appear at layer 3 and not on any of the parent nodes.

Kind regards

Comment: The project is in WinForms

Comment: And I think I accidentally deleted someone's comment.

Comment: Nope, I deleted it myself ... I like to clean up comments as soon as things are clarified.